# How to handle with multiple selection ListBox? asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

In my aspx registration page i have more then 6 item available in my list box, I am allowing multiple selection on it..I am not sure about how many items i will select each and every time. then how i have to store it into dataset and how to pass it as a mysql paramter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [`ListBox.SelectionMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectionmode(VS.71).aspx) property. Loop through the selected items to add into your datasource.